# 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'

Tags: r

I received the error

```
Error in if (x[i] == 0 && x[i - 1] > 0) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

when running this function on a numeric vector

```
number_rn <- function(x) {
  a <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] == 0 && x[i-1] > 0) {
      a <- a +1
    }
  }
  print(a)
}
```

However, the following function works fine:

```
number_rr <- function(x) {
  a <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] > 0 && x[i-1] > 0) {
      a <- a +1
    }
  }
  print(a)
}
```

I note from previous answers to similar questions that this can occur if the `if` conditional does not have either a `TRUE` or `FALSE` result, but I do not believe this to be the case in my example. What could be causing this error?

Comment: What vector did you run the function on?

Comment: it's likely that `i` is bigger than `x`'s length. anyway one of your term is NA, check `i`, `x[i]`, `x[i-1]` ...

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely occurring because you vector x has NULL or NA values. See what happens when I try to run a if condition with NULL values -

```
x <- NULL
if (x == 0 && x > 5) print("yes")
```

Make sure to remove any NAs or NULLs using is.na() or is.null() and you should be fine

Comment: No NULL or NA values in my vector. However I believe that the issue arises when the first element of my vector is zero. As in this case x[i] == 0 evaluates to true and x[i-1] > 0 to NA. Perhaps the solution would be to skip to the next element if x[1] = 0? If so, any ideas how? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the for loop (even if `x` does not contain any `NA` values):

1. In the first iteration (`i == 1`), `x[i-1]` refers to `x[0]` which is undefined as indexing in R starts at `1`.
2. The code is using a for loop where vectorized functions can be used.

Unfortunately, starting the loop at `i == 2`, i.e., `for (i in 2:length(x))`, is not error-proof in case of a one element vector where `length(x) == 1`.

My suggestion is to use the vectorized version

```
number_rn_vec <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  sum(x[2:n] == 0 & x[1:(n - 1)] > 0, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

This will return `a` without error for many use cases:

```
sapply(
  list(
    c(),
    c(1),
    c(1, 0),
    c(1, 0, 3),
    c(0, 1, 0, 3),
    c(NA, 1, 0, 3),
    c(1, NA, 0, 3),
    c(1, 0, NA, 3),
    c(1, 0, 3, NA)
  ),
  number_rn_vec
)
```

> ```
> [1] 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
> ```